# i use queue but thy can't run with dispatch

Tags: laravel

I have use queue laravel but the can't run it with dispatch

```
$this->dispatch(new myClass());
```

But still not work in the queue dive I use the sync and with a larval async queue drive from github

on my controller:

```
$this->dispatch(new SendMails($reservation));
```

Comment: first run `php artisan queue:work --queue=high,default`..

Comment: but if i run this i need to run it avery time

Comment: It should keep running on background ...

Comment: You should use supervisor  http://supervisord.org/installing.html

Comment: but when i use this command the run it more thene one time

Comment: Use supervisor or set cron

Comment: another option is to use horizon...  https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/horizon